# ¿Como crear e implementar un scoped service en Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, inyeccion-de-dependencias, quartz

Estoy creando una tarea programada con Quartz.Net  en  Asp.Net Core 5.0, ya lo había hecho en versiones posteriores y todo bien  con este ejemplo del siguiente enlace:

https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/

Pero ahora me da el siguiente error en el momento en que se invoca la tarea:

***Cannot resolve 'IntegracionDocu.Commons.QuartzDescargaProgramada' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.***

*(“Entiendo que debo crear un servicio scoped para que lo consuma el singleton”)
NO SE COMO HACERLO??*

Encontré esto  que debe ir en la clase QuartzDescargaProgramada  pero no sé de donde sale el `IScopedService`

```
 public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Create a new scope
        using(var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
        {
            // Resolve the Scoped service
            var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IScopedService>();
            _logger.LogInformation("Ejecutandose!");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Mi código

Starup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Agregamos servicio  Quartz
            services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
            services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
            // Agregamos nuestro trabajo programado
            services.AddSingleton<QuartzDescargaProgramada>();
            services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(jobType: typeof(QuartzDescargaProgramada), cronExpression: "0 54 22 ? * *"));
            services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();
         
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es solamente si quieres utilizar algún otro servicio Scoped dentro del Job.

En este caso, no mencionas qué servicio Scoped quieres utilizar, además, no tienes ningún Scoped registrado, por lo que no creo que sea necesario en tu caso.

En lugar de IScopedService debería de ir la interfaz o implementación del servicio Scoped que vayas a utilizar dentro de tu Job.

Un ejemplo sería si tuvieras un servicio Scoped `ValueService`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddScoped<ValueService>(); // Registro de ValueService
}
```

y quisieras utilizarlo en tu Job:

```cs
public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
   // Create a new scope
   using(var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
   {
      // Resolve the Scoped service
      var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ValueService>();
      _logger.LogInformation("Ejecutandose!");
   }

   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```